SSD won't boot on new motherboard
This MBR-partitioned SSD with Windows 10 on it won't boot on my new Biostar H310M motherboard.
Yet this very same SSD used to work on my previous motherboard.
My new motherboard is configured for both UEFI & Legacy boot.
Weirdly enough, the SSD is only recognized on SATA 3 or 4, not on SATA 1 or 2.
I have not done any bootsect repair yet.
https://imgur.com/a/eLgpaQc
Any suggestion?

Have you enabled CSM mode in BIOS? Windows doesn't boot from MBR if BIOS is in UEFI mode.

The best solution is backup any personal files you need and reinstall in UEFI mode and GPT.

The SSD is recognized on SATA 3 or 4 because probably thats the connecter being used. But thats not important. Whats important is the boot priority. Change that from the bios and make sure that the SSD is on number 1 in boot priorty. That should help.

But the Boot Options priorities is greyed out in my BIOS (see 3rd picture).
